# MT4 plugin is correct to use c++-cli

Tags: c++-cli, mt4

I am just wondering is it ok to use c++/CLI to interract with the MT4ServerAPI istead of native c++? Does it cause any problem to use c++/cli? I know it is working just fine but I get some warnings about .NET is not recommended to use with MT4. Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: I do't know what is MT4, but the API offers a support for .Net ?

Comment: MT4 is used for FOREX. it can only integrate with c++ plugins. I have tried to use c++/cli plugin and it also works, so I guess it does offer support for .net. The thing is maybe it can work ok, however I have warnings that it is not too safe to use .net with MT4. So, I want to know why it is not recommended? what problems may arise? Thank you!

Comment: MT4 can only access standard calls of unmanaged DLLs

Comment: there is solution like NQuotes (http://www.nquotes.net/) otherwise

Comment: NQuotes is used to Mql with c# :) so it is not what I am looking for! Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

C++/CLI is capable of having one foot in the native world, and the other in the .NET CLR. As such, it can talk to both environments - and is often used to bridge between the two.

There is no problem doing this, but MT4 would be completely unaware it has any connection with the .NET world - since C++/CLI is performing any marshalling itself.